# Вывести записи только нужной категории с пагинацией

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Вот код

```
<?php
    $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $params = array(
        'paged'          => $current_page,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'category'      => '4'
    );
    query_posts($params);    
    $wp_query->is_archive = true;
    $wp_query->is_home = false;
    ?><ul><?
    while(have_posts()): the_post();
        ?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?
    endwhile;
    ?></ul><?
    wp_reset_postdata();
    the_posts_pagination();
    wp_reset_query();   
?>
```

Так выводятся посты со всех рубрик. А нужно только с рубрики у которой ID = 4. Как это сделать? И чтобы пагинация работала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$params = array(
            'paged'          => $current_page,
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type'      => 'post',
            // 'category'       => '4'
            'category_name' => 'publications_2'
        );
```